# Show that exist a singular k-chain $c^{k}$

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $\omega\neq 0$, a differential k-form, define in a open subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Show that exist a singular k-chain $c^{k}$ such that $$\int_{c^{k}}{\omega}\neq 0$$

I know that, a singular k-chain in U is a formal sum of singular k-cubes $c_{i}^{k}$ in U with integer coefficients $l_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}$, $l_{1}c_{1}^{k}+\cdots+l_{m}c_{m}^{k}=s^{k}$, but How I can prove that "exist" a singular k-chain. Regards!

|Edit, I have a second question Show that $d^{2}=0$.
Is sufficiently we can Stokes theorem?? Regards!

Answer (score 2):

Write the form in coordinates $$\omega = \omega_{i_1 \cdots i_k} dx^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_k}$$ and choose a point $p$ where $\omega$ is non-vanishing. Since $\omega(p)\ne 0$, it has some non-zero component there; that is, there is a multi-index $I = i_1 \cdots i_k$ such that $\omega_I(p) \ne 0$. We can assume $\omega_I(p) > 0$ (by possibly permuting the order of the $i_j$), and thus by continuity we get a neighbourhood of $p$ on which $\omega_I > 0$.

Now just choose a $k$-cube $c$ aligned to the axes corresponding to $I$ of edge length $\epsilon$ small enough that it lies inside this neighbourhood, so that we have $$\int_c \omega = \int_{[0,\epsilon]^k} \omega_I,$$ which is the integral of a positive function and is thus positive.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How I can prove that $d^{2}=0$?? Regards!

Comment: @asdasdasd Your question in the last comment seems *completely* unrelated to this post. If you have another question, please consider writing a new post.